# Diffeomorphisms fixing origin and boundary

Tags: lie-groups, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Let $D^n$ be a disc in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Is there a known characterization of all the diffeomorphisms of $D^n$ fixing the origin and boundary of $D^n$?

Comment: @DanieleZuddas: Is that really true? How to see that? The number of connected components of the space of all diffeomorphisms fixing the boundary (but not the origin) is pretty complicated.

Comment: And I would guess the map $\mathrm{Diff}_\partial (D^n)\rightarrow \mathrm{int}(D^n)$ that sends a diffeomorphism that preserves the boundary to its evaluation at $0$ is a fibration with fiber the space in the OP. That would mean that the homotopy groups are the same.

Comment: http://people.math.harvard.edu/~kupers/teaching/272x/book.pdf

Comment: They are not all isotopic to the identity.  Roughly speaking in high dimensions there is a bijection between these isotopy classes and the group of exotic $(n+1)$-spheres.  Getting back to the original question, what kind of characterization do you want?  You could view the homotopy-type of these diffeomorphism groups as the "generators" of the difference between the categories of topological and smooth manifolds.

Comment: As others say the diffeomorphism group of $D^n$ rel boundary is complicated, see e.g. http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/Diff%28M%292012.pdf.

Comment: you are all right! thanks, I remove my comment

Comment: @ThomasRot Independent of the original question, that looks like an interesting book. Thanks for posting a link.